# How to compare geometry in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, gis, sqlgeometry

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I have this column of type `geometry` in my table:

```
POINT (34.8780917279395 32.1872894246816)
```

In another table I also have a column of type `geometry`:

```
0xE6100000010CB3314B4F6570414073F29019F9174040
```

How can I compare these columns, to determine whether it is the same point?

Comment: What database? What field types are these two?

Comment: @ArtemNovikov it's I use SQLServer2012 and  field of geometry type.\

Comment: Do you really want to compare the points for *equality*? Usually, I'd expect to compute the *distance*, and then determine whether it's "close enough" for whatever purposes you're performing the comparison.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Because It should be two same points and the distance between them must be 0

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you will read in the documentation. When I need to compare geometries i usually add second geometry column that contains a MD5-hash of the geometry. The comparison is faster than traditionally geometry comparison. The sql statements also gets clearer.

However, there is an extra complexity keeping MD5-hash updated, and it may also be some pitfall with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Geometries can only be compared when [SRIDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964707.aspx) are equal. Take a look at following example (intentionally expanded):

```
WITH Geometries AS
(
    SELECT
        --Convert to geometry)
        CAST(0xE6100000010CB3314B4F6570414073F29019F9174040 AS geometry) GB,
        --Get SRID          
        CAST(0xE6100000010CB3314B4F6570414073F29019F9174040 AS geometry).STSrid STSrid
)
SELECT
    STSrid,--SRID, make sure point 'belongs' to correct SRID
    GB.STDistance(geometry::STPointFromText('POINT(34.8780917279395 32.1872894246816)', STSrid)) Distance
FROM Geometries
```

If points are exact copies, you can compare geometry/binary representations as well. STDistance is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

For the Second table, you need to convert the point from WKB to geom format. Try below to get the geom and compare with first point.

```
DECLARE @g geometry;   
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromWKB(0xE6100000010CB3314B4F6570414073F29019F9174040, 0);  
SELECT @g.STAsText();
```